# Sublime Text 2 - Files won't update

Tags: file, editor, sublimetext2

When I add files via the terminal, Sublime doesn't seem to pick up the changes. I have to remove the project and re-add it to sublime for the files to show up. Does anyone know of a solution to this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: this issue exists for me too, almost every time I start sublime and try to create new files - they are not appearing to folder tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I'm not entirely sure what exactly caused it, or how this resolved it, but I opened the project up and removed all folders from the project.  I quit ST2 and opened it back up, then re-added the folders.  Since then everything works fine, files update, and I'm once again to get saved changes to overwrite files on the local filesystem (it wasn't doing that before either).

I've shut it down and started it back up repeatedly, and was able to confirm every time that it was picking up new changes I had made to some files via vim.